# How can I hide my HTML table, when a search is finished?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to let my HTML table load up hidden, and it only displays the "hits" that matches accordingly to the user's search, and whenever a search is not happening, the table should go back to being hidden.

```
<html>
 <table id="dvExcel"></table>   
</html>

<style>
  #dvExcel{
    display: none;
   }
</style>

<script>
function myFunction() {
//this is the search function

var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
input = document.getElementById("myInput"); 
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();        
and store
table = document.getElementById("dvExcel"); 
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");     


    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];  
            if (td ) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {

                table.style.display = "block";
                tr[i].style.display = "";


            }else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";

             }
            }
    }
}

</script>
```

My HTML table loads hidden, and everytime I search it displays the hits, but the table will not go back to being hidden when I remove the text in the search box. Instead it displays the whole table.

Comment: Maybe try to hide the Div or the parent HTML of the table and not the table itself.

Comment: Do an interval check on the search, if no text then display=none.

Answer (score 0):

You set the table to block but never set it back to none. Using your existing for loop, add a check to see if any hits were found or not. If none were found hide the whole table, rather than just the rows.

```
var foundHit = false; // Add this
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];  
            if (td ) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {

                table.style.display = "block";
                tr[i].style.display = "";
                foundHit = true; // Add this

            }else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";

             }
            }
    }
    if (!foundHit) table.style.display = "none"; // Add this
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the display style of the table to none when nothing is found:

```
table.style.display = "none";
```

Here is the complete working code:

```js
var theButton = document.getElementById("b1");
theButton.onclick = myFunction1;
theButton = document.getElementById("b2");
theButton.onclick = myFunction2;

function myFunction1() {
  myFunction ('something');
}

function myFunction2() {
  myFunction ();
}
function myFunction (myInput) {
    var table = document.getElementById("dvExcel");
    var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");     
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];  
        if (td ) {
            if (myInput) {
                table.style.display = "block";
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                table.style.display = "none";
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
  #dvExcel {
    display: none;
   }
```

```html
<h3>
table show/hide test
</h3>
 <table id="dvExcel"><tr><td>This is the table. It is visible now.</td></tr></table>  
 <button id="b1">
 find something
 </button>
<button id="b2">
 don't find anything
 </button>
```